# Devise skip authentication on /assets requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I concede that this is more of a nuisance in development and will be less troublesome in production, but even in production, I don't want devise to be authenticating or adding any overhead whatsoever to `/assets` requests.

In development, we see a slew of the following (currently about 30 for each of our asset files):

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-01 11:53:40 -0500
  AfCore::User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 8  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

I looked and couldn't find any options related to skipping assets, and I don't see where we explicitly added them unless something like `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` is causing this.

How can we have devise skip all asset requests?

Comment: This is not a problem of Devise, it has something to do with your Gemfile or with something related to your configuration. Although if you leave it in development like this it won't matter much because you can always configure NGINX to serve static assets in production mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be causing this, any pointers?  As I mention, I'm less worried about production because we have static serving there, plus a CDN.  It's really a painful development irritation.

Comment: The only way I could replicate your problem was by renaming "application.js" to "application.js.erb" and putting "<% User.first %>" in it. I think you have a dynamic JS file which is fetching current user's detail to put some dynamic data into it.

Comment: `User.first` or the equivalent would have to be in every asset file, and it isn't. The `AfCore::User Load` line happens for each `GET` asset, and we have about 30 assets.  I double checked to be sure, but this is clearly coming from a framework or common rack component etc.

Comment: sorry man, I think I won't know the answer until I see some source-code.

Comment: Thanks @Parry, got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have access to the source code and it is related to a rack component. Calling warden.user in a rack component is request based and will query for the user for each request. Here is the code used to diagnose:

```
puts 'before warden.user'
if warden.presence && warden.user.presence
  security_context.user = warden.user
end
puts 'after warden.user'
```

and the console output:

```
before warden.user
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
after warden.user
```

*****EDIT*****

This can be skipped with:

```
def call(rack_env)

  if rack_env['PATH_INFO'] =~ /^\/assets/
    # avoid retrieving the session's user for unnecessary calls -  assets/validators
    @app.call(rack_env)
  else
    ...
    # warden.user stuff
    ...
    @app.call(rack_env)
  end
```